# How can we generate same hash code from same String using SHA256 or else in iOS & android in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, hash

There are some solutions to generate same hash code in android & iOS using native programming language (Swift & Java or Kotlin).

How can I do the same using dart language in Flutter?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto) .

usage:

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; // for the utf8.encode method

void main() {
  var bytes = utf8.encode("MyString"); // data being hashed

  var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);

  print("Digest as bytes: ${digest.bytes}");
  print("Digest as hex string: $digest");
}
```

Comment: When I encode strings such as this character ( " ) to byte List, it gives me different represents between iOS and android:

in android: [34].
in iOS: [226,128,156].